# I want to enter only a certain number of elements into each row of the array. How do I do that?

Tags: c

I'm trying to enter only a certain number of elements into this 2D array like this:

```
AEF
FECCF
ERE
RRGT
EHWEG
```

The current loop does this:

```
for(loop = 0; loop < routines; loop++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &danceRoutines[loop][j]);
    }
}
```

This is the code I have to scan in the elements. I understand that this makes it so that I enter MAX amount of elements in the columns (MAX = 26). How do I make it so that after I enter a number of elements less than MAX, it allows me to enter into the next row of the 2D array? Thank you

Comment: Use something besides a fixed-iteration for-loop. Personally I'd use `fgets` and trim the newline for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can implement this.Create a `char**` array `danceRoutines` which will point to the strings, and then assign the address of every new string entered by user to the `danceRoutines[i]` inside the loop.

```
int routines=5,loop;
char **danceRoutines=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*routines);
for(loop = 0; loop < routines; loop++)
{
    char *s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    scanf("%s",s);
    danceRoutines[loop]=s;
}
```

Then simply display the strings by iterating over array `danceRoutines`

```
//display
for(loop = 0; loop < routines; loop++)
{
    printf("%s\n",danceRoutines[loop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First ask how many elements has to be entered, before entering the loop to read elements.

```
int elements;
for(loop = 0; loop < routines; loop++)
{
    printf("enter number of elements for row %d\n", loop + 1);
    scanf("%d", &elements);    //read the number of elements
    for(j = 0; j < elements; j++)
    {
        scanf(" %c", &danceRoutines[loop][j]);
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE:**

Notice the space before `%c` in `scanf()`. That is required to clear the input buffer.